# split a string (into chunks)based on my db varchar size

Tags: java, database, string, varchar, chunks

I want to split a string into series of the substring to fit into my DB where say my DB varchar size is 50. And if, on cutting the original string up to 50 chars, then I need to include the trailing, (comma) with that string. for eg,

my original string - 
**[test, datttaaa, testinnggg, proggrrammmm, stringsOpsss, anottttaation, springgmvc, test, data]**

1. cutting the original string up to 50 chars and it will be **[test, datttaaa, testinnggg, proggrrammmm, strings** Here the substring is to **strings** and I want to cut it till up to trailing, (comma). So I will be assigning this chunk up to **[test, datttaaa, testinnggg, proggrrammmm,**
2. Now replacing the original string with leftover chunks, **stringsOpsss, anottttaation, springgmvc, test, data]** Repeating the above process, my output will look like below,

**[test, datttaaa, testinnggg, proggrrammmm,**

**stringsOpsss, anottttaation, springgmvc, test,**

**data]**

Hence will be having 3 db insert rows. Written a program for this,

```
    int maxRowSize = 50; //db column varchar size
    String rowChunk;
    String orgString;
    StrData2 sData = new StrData2();
    orgString= sData.getData();
    while(orgString.length() > maxRowSize) {
        rowChunk = orgString.substring(0, maxRowSize);
        rowChunk = rowChunk.substring(0,rowChunk.lastIndexOf(",")+1);
        System.out.println(rowChunk);
        orgString= orgString.substring(rowChunk.length()+1,orgString.length());
    }
    System.out.println(orgString);
```

Is there any better approach than the above one or any alternative APIs that we can use to simplify?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks good. I do not know any library who could solve this problem better or make it more easy.

Answer (score 0):

try this one (not tested but should work)

```
public static void main(String[] s) {

        String str = " test, datttaaa, testinnggg, proggrrammmm, stringsOpsss, anottttaation, springgmvc, test, data";
        String[] strArray = str.split(",");
        List<String> outputArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        stringUpTo50Length( Arrays.asList(strArray), outputArray, "");

        for(String s1:outputArray) {
            System.out.println(s1);
        }

    }
    public static void stringUpTo50Length(List<String> strInputArray, List<String> strOutputArray, String outString) {
    for (int i=0; i<strInputArray.size(); i++ ) {
        if (outString.length() + strInputArray.get(i).length() <=50) {
            outString= outString + "," + strInputArray.get(i);
        } else {
            strOutputArray.add(outString.substring(1));
            outString = "";
            stringUpTo50Length(strInputArray.subList(i, strInputArray.size()), strOutputArray, outString);
            break;
        }

    }
    if (outString.equals("")==false) {
        strOutputArray.add(outString.substring(1));
        outString="";
    }
```

}

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but it seems **strOutputArray** has string upto anottttaation **[test, datttaaa, testinnggg, proggrrammmm,  proggrrammmm, stringsOpsss, anottttaation]**

Also its printing duplicates like below
**test, datttaaa, testinnggg, proggrrammmm

 proggrrammmm, stringsOpsss, anottttaation **

Comment: so is it possible to do with guava ? I tried with guava's splitter but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: replace i-1 to i: like below                stringUpTo50Length(strInputArray.subList(i, strInputArray.size()), strOutputArray, outString);

Comment: thanks @Panbe . Your approach is trying to add elements from array one by one and then comparing the concatenated length with upto 50. And then calling it again recursively if exceeds 50. And also when I tried to add strOutputArray.add(outString); at the end of method stringUpTo50Length(), to include the last element in the array, it doesn't give expected because of the recursion. So I think I would stick with the old one. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: sure. i just shared the idea not real implementation.

Comment: team wants to go for the first approach and my leads too.. so implemented the first one.. anyways thanks @PanBe